# time.sleep() acting before its supposed to?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement something in my app that displays some data to the user, before asking them through a tkinter `messagebox` if they want to write this data to a .txt file. I want the code to halt for a few seconds so the user has time to read the info before being asked if they want to write it to a .txt file.

```
#Output data to tkinter window
for piece in self.Data:
    Label(self.MainFrame, text=piece).pack()

#Halt execution for a few seconds so that the user has time to see data.
time.sleep(10)

#Message box to ask user if they want to write the data to an external .txt file
AskWrite = messagebox.askyesno('Write to file', 'Do you want to write this data to a .txt file?')
```

Currently, all this is doing is waiting 10 seconds, before showing the message box, and only showing the data in the window once an option has been selected at the message box. I want it so  that the data is first displayed in the window, before the program waits 10 seconds, and then a message box comes up after those 10 seconds.

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks execution. Presumably, this is a single-threaded application, and so the main thread never has a chance to handle events and update the GUI, since you're blocking execution - that's why you don't see the Labels updating. Look into the `after` method, which every tkinter widget has. It'll let you bind a callback to be triggered after a certain number of milliseconds have elapsed.

Comment: @PaulM. Thank you. I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

tkinter.after will work for calling a function after a certain number of milliseconds and updating the window correctly, as a commenter suggests. However, if you want to use time.sleep, the issue you have is that the window is not updating. You can force the window to update beforehand by calling self.MainFrame.update() before time.sleep.